# How to install Perl Module DBD:Oracle: Oracle 10g (32 bit) and Perl 5.18 (64 bit)

Tags: oracle, perl

I have problem when try to install Perl module DBD:Oracle with below env

- Fedora 20 64 bit
- Perl 5.18 64 bit
- Oracle 10g 32 bit

When try to make, it inform below error

```
Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::Oracle ()
chmod 644 Oracle.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so
gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro  Oracle.o dbdimp.o oci8.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so    \
   -L/usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib/ -lclntsh -lpthread -lperl     \
/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/lib/oracle/xe/app/oracle/product/10.2.0/server/lib//libclntsh.so when searching for -lclntsh
/bin/ld: cannot find -lclntsh
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [blib/arch/auto/DBD/Oracle/Oracle.so] Error 1
  PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.74.tar.gz
  /bin/make -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Can't test without successful make
Running make install
  Make had returned bad status, install seems impossible
Failed during this command:
 PYTHIAN/DBD-Oracle-1.74.tar.gz               : make NO
```

It seems that Perl try to search for Oralce 64bit lib but can not and error occur.

Can any one help me on this if I need to config anything before build the package?

Thanks,
Quang

Comment: Your machine is 64 bit, your Perl is 64 bit, but your Oracle is 32 bit. Can you install the 64 bit version of Oracle? I see the error `skipping incompatible .../libclntsh.so`. If the file exists, it could be that the 32 bit version of that file can't be used in the compile phase.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I wonder if there is a way to config Perl 64 use Oracle 32 lib?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked with the C compiler. However, 32 bit code cannot be compiled on a 64 bit system without a 32 bit compatible compiler and a complete set of 32 bit libraries. I doubt 32 bit compiled code can work with 64 bit compiled Perl. However, others more familiar with C might know better.

Comment: I removed the Oracle 32 and then install Oracle 64, everything is ok now.
Thx all :)